# How to enable SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 cipher in java 8 server?

Tags: java, tcp

I have an test environment client application which uses SSLv3 and SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 cipher suite. I need to use SSLv3 client because it cannot be changed now. I enabled Java server (running on java 8 JVM) to allow SSLv3 and RC4 cipher suites by editing java.security file. I know that java 8 has disabled RC4 for security reasons.

When I run the java 8 client to connect to java 8 server with SSLv3 and SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 cipher suite, I am getting error "SSLHandshakeException:no cipher suites in common" because the client is sending SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 and Server does not know about SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5.

java 8 is supposed to have enabled SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 cipher suite by default. see [Cipher suites in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html)

if I run the server in java 6 then client can connect and everything works. I would like to use java 8 in the server.

is there a way to enable SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 cipher suite in Java 8.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting error "SSLHandshakeException:no cipher suites in common" because the client is sending SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 and Server does not know about SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5.

But it does. You said so. This message can also mean that the server couldn't find its own certificate and private key.

Comment: EJP,  Its good that you pointed that the exception can be thrown when the server cannot find its own certificate. How does the server know what is its certificate? can you please elaborate.